# 60 amp incoming service to house, am I in need of an upgrade?

Tags: wiring

I have a house that has knob and tube wiring. I'm going to replace all of it with romex because I can't find an insurance company that will ensure my house. I'm wondering if it would be a good idea to replace my 60 amp service with 100 amp or just leave it as 60. This would require upgrading the homerun wires coming into my box.

Comment: Future you will appreciate a bigger panel. (Resale value, renovating the kitchen, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this yourself, will it be inspected?  IE are you going to pull a permit?  If so, I seriously doubt an inspector would approve of modern Romex being connected to an ancient fuse box.   Bring in large 200 amp panel and replace the meter base.  Since 200 amp panels are so common they dont cost that much more than smaller panels  .  Also get a PON (plug on neutral) to make for a very neat install.  You'll probably be required to upgrade to AFCI or GFCI breakers as well.